# Angular-firebase. Search an array of objects by $id

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have this array of objects :

[image: img]

**I want to get the $id and $id.name values.**

```
var CitiesFactory = function(){
    var ref = new Firebase("https://starmeteo.firebaseio.com/");
    return ref.child('cities');
}
```

I tried `console.log($firebaseArray(CitiesFactory).$indexFor('bucuresti'));`
it returns -1 (not found)

I also tried with `$getRecord` and got the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Use AngularFire for synchronizing data from Firebase that you want to bind to AngularJS views. With your current factory:

```
$scope.cities = $firebaseArray(CitiesFactory());

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat='(id, city) in cities'>{{city.Name}} - {{id}}</li>
</ol>
```

For most cases where you're not binding to a view, you're often better of using the [Firebase JavaScript SDK](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/) directly.

With the latter, you can do what you want with:

```
CitiesFactory().on('value', function(citiesSnapshot) {
  citiesSnapshot.forEach(function(citySnapshot) {
    console.log(citySnapshot.key, citySnapshot.val().name);
  });
});
```

This will print all city keys (what's shown as `$id` by AngularFire) and all names *whenever* a city is add, changed or removed.